# Volley authentication error in my project

Tags: android, exception, android-volley

I am working on a project and i continuously throwing exception "com.android.volley.AuthFailureError"  i have wasted my 2 days on it. Please if anyone having best solution do comment. 
pramaters are
"email:h4@gmail.com
name:h3
lat:123456
lng:123456
role:customer
address:13246546543213
lat_lng:012354
password:123456
id:123456
zipcode:123456"

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://webmarke8.com/gincart/api/login", new Response.Listener<String>() {



            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    progress.hide();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progress.dismiss();

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Side Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parse Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put("email","muhammadaqeelprivate@gmail.com");
                map.put("password","123456789");
                return map;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: An *AuthFailureError* usually means your request failed authorization. You don't seem to be placing any authentication parameters or authorization tokens in your request. How do you login/authenticate to the API?

Comment: sir there is no authentication parameters is given in the api